# Can any number of the form $4k+2$ be written as $a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$?

Tags: quadratics

Can any number of the form $4k+2$ be written as $a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$?

Comment: Every odd number is the difference of two squares

Comment: If $a,b$ are odd and $c,d$ are even , then $a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2\equiv 2 \mod 4$ . So  in short , *Yes*.

Comment: $a=\sqrt{4k+2},b=0,c=0,d=0$

Answer (score 9):

Here is one way:

$$4k+2=(k+1)^2+(k+1)^2-k^2-k^2$$

Answer (score 0):

The [OEIS sequence A042965](https://oeis.org/A042965)
is the sequence of nonnegative integers not congruent
to 2 mod 4. It is also the nonnegative integers that
can be written as a difference of two integer squares. 
Thus for all $\,n\,$ **not** of the form 
$\,4k+2\,$ we have $\,n = a^2-b^2\,$ and for those
 of the form $\,4k+2\,$ we have
 $\, n = a^2+1^2-b^2.\,$ 
Thus, for all nonnegative integers $\,n\,$ we can find integers $\,a,b,c,d\,$ such that
$\,n=a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2.$